# Selecting an alternate EditorFor template for a List

Tags: model-view-controller, editorfor, editortemplates

I have an object that represents a food item to order at a restaurant. This object has a list of Modifier Groups (sides, cooking instructions, pizza toppings, whatever) and each list has a list of Modifiers.

Certain Modifier options need to be displayed differently (for example, toppings need to specify left/right/all), even though they are the same data type.

I am trying use @Html.EditorFor and specify the alternate EditorTemplate when required.

In /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates I have ModifierSelection.cshtml and ToppingSelection.cshtml. I am calling them in the following view:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.ModifierSelectionList

<div class="menugroup">
    <h3 class="menuname">@Model.ModifierListName: (Select @Model.MaximumSelections)</h3>
    <div class="modcountvalidation">@Model.ValidationResults</div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ModifierListId)

    <table class="menu">
    @if (Model.IsToppingsList)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.ModifierSelections, "ToppingSelection")
    }
    else
    { 
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.ModifierSelections)
    }
    </table>
</div>
```

When I try to display an item that requires the "ToppingSelection" EditorTemplate instead of the default, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyApp.ViewModels.ModifierSelection]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyApp.ViewModels.ModifierSelection'.
  Source=System.Web.Mvc
```

So - I have a set of EditorTemplates for a data type. I am trying to use them to display a list of items and I need to be able to select which one to use.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here is the real solution. Rather than iterating through the list using foreach, I had to iterate using a for loop.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ModifierSelections.Count; i++ )
{
    if (Model.IsToppingsList)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.ModifierSelections[i], "ToppingSelection")
    }
    else
    { 
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.ModifierSelections[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Apparently, if you send a list type to Html.EditorFor and do not specify a template, it will iterate through the list and display each item using the template that it finds for the item type. If you do specify a template, it will not iterate through the list and send each item to that template, it will attempt to send the entire list to your template, which isn't the right data type.

I fixed it by manually iterating through the list:

```
@foreach (var modifierSelection in Model.ModifierSelections)
{
    if (Model.IsToppingsList)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => modifierSelection, "ToppingSelection")
    }
    else
    { 
        @Html.EditorFor(m => modifierSelection)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong - I this doesn't work. It displays properly, but the data isn't returned back to the view in the model. Apparently, if you specify an alternate template in EditorFor, it won't iterate for a list type, but if I manually iterate the list, then it doesn't properly wire up model. Is there a way to do this?